# Setcookie > sniff > output on same page

Tags: php, cookies, sniffing

I wonder if someone can help shed some light on this:

I drop a cookie if a user arrives to the site with a specific key/value in query string. i.e.: http://www.somesite.com?key=hmm01

The cookie code exists at top of the template before `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML )` :

`<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
ob_start();
if (isset($_GET['key'])) {
    setcookie("cookname", $_GET['key'], time()+2592000); /* Expires in a month */
}
ob_end_flush();
?>`

On the same page though within the  : I have the following php code that sniffs the cookie and outputs some text:

`

switch ($cookievalue)
{
case hmm01: 
  echo "abc";
  break;
case hmm02: 
  echo "def";
  break;
case hmm03: 
  echo "ghi";
  break;
default:
  echo "hello";
}
?>`

-- Problem is when the user first arrives the sniffer script doesn't detect the cookie and outputs the default text: hello
Only when user refreshes page or navigates to a different page does the sniffer detect the cookie.

Any ideas on how to drop the cookie and output the correct text without a page refresh?

Many thanks.

Comment: what's the use of ob start here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check $_GET for the first time:

```
if(isset($_GET['key'])) { $cookievalue = $_GET['key']; }
if(isset($_COOKIE['cookname'])) { $cookievalue = $_COOKIE['cookname']; }

switch ($cookievalue) { case hmm01: echo "abc"; break; case hmm02: echo "def"; break; case hmm03: echo "ghi"; break; default: echo "hello"; } ?>
```

Comment: Great thanks Alec - that worked. Damn I should really have figured that one out :~

Answer (score 0):

if (specific key/value in query string) $_COOKIE['cookname'] = "some value";

And learn some HTTP